# How to validate async api response with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do I validate my API response when storing it as an object. For example:

```
const { data } = await axios.get("/form");
```

How do I make sure this data conforms to:

```
interface Form {
    title: string;
    questions: Question[]
}
```

Comment: Using typescript? You can't, it doesn't exist at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

Typescript does not perform any type of validations out of the box like java or other strong typed languages.

Things like

```
const { data } = await axios.get<Form>("/form");
```

does not guarantee that the response data is of Form type. It is just used for static typing checks (no errors/validation in runtime). For having a guarantee I would recommend the implementation of a guard function (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) with some JSON schema validation. For example, you can use
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ajv or https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi package to do that.

Comment: P.S. there are packages that allow generating interfaces from JSON schemas https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-schema-to-typescript.
P.P.S. the same JSON schemas may be shared between BE and FE validators. And a lot of devs interpreter JSON schemas as a guarantee (contract) which is the source of truth.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
const { data } = await axios.get<Form>("/form");
```

If you want to make sure that the incoming data is indeed compatible with `Form` interface, you have to do it in runtime (thus can't be done with `TS`). Checking runtime data is compatible with a type isn't always straightforward or easy (especially with nested data). [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) is one of the libraries that does it.