# Check if all properties exist in an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a service where objects come through and sometimes could be missing a field. I am building a validation method to check the object to see if it's missing any properties.

For example, lets say I have a type person

```
interface person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    eyeColor: string;
}
```

and an object of type person comes in

```
{
    name: "Joe",
    eyeColor: "brown",
}
```

I want to throw an error saying that "age" is missing from the object. Is it possible in typescript to check if an object has all the properties of its type?

Comment: If it's from another service then typescript doesnot provide you with the functionality. Maybe you are looking for a package like joi or Ajv JSON schema validator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate async api response with Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66861315/how-to-validate-async-api-response-with-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

There are some libraries that can do this for you. For instance [zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#basic-usage).

This would look something like this:

```
const Person = z.object({
    name: z.string(),
    age: z.number(),
    eyeColor: z.string()
});

type Person = z.infer<typeof Person>;
```

And then you can do:

```
Person.parse(myData); // throw if it does not match the schema.
```

There's a couple more of this kind of libraries, you can google Typescript runtime validation to find some more.